# Looking for a formula to check if a URL from one cell is contained in another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a long list of URLs in one column, and in the column to the right of it another URL, but wrapped in an  href attribute.

I am trying to find a formula that checks to see if the URL contained inside the  href for each row in column B matches the URL in the same row in column A, and returns TRUE or FALSE.

I have attached an image to illustrate what I mean.

[image: link to image]

I've tried playing around with the REGEXMATCH function but I don't seem to be coming up with the answer.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try in C2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(B2:B; A2:A))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After trying your solution it seems to work but only for certain URLs. Could this be due to it not allowing non A-Z 0-9 symbols?

Comment: @Tom can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Just after typing my previous reply, I thought of a workaround, to use an =MID and FIND function to extract part of the URLs in to another field and then check for exact matches that way. It seems to be working. Really appreciate your time and help, @player0

Answer (score 0):

What about conditional formating the two rows with a custom formula? E.g.,

```
=countif(A1:A,A1)>1
```